# Comment exprimer le « water bike » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, néologismes, sport

[J'ai lu](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/insolite/2022-07-11/en-belgique-on-s-affronte-sur-des-velos-flottants.php) qu'il y avait une compétition de « water-bike » en Belgique ; dans l'article on parle de *vélos flottants* qui « se composent d’un cadre de vélo posé sur deux flotteurs » (LaPresse) ; mais on pourrait imaginer un vélo flottant dont la force motrice provient de roues conventionnelles modifiées. L'[*aquacycle*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aquacycle) est quant à lui essentiellement une bicyclette stationnaire immergée. Je connais aussi le [*pédalo*](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8418831), qui semble-t-il est surtout associé à un produit (marque de commerce). Qui dit mieux ?

---

Pense-t-on que « vélo flottant » est adéquat et pourquoi, et quel pourrait être un meilleur terme (néologisme ou autrement) qui s'intégrerait au lexique existant (cohérence) tout en s'appuyant sur ce qui est naturel en français ?

Answer (score 1):

À l'écrit au moins, ***cycl'eau*** utilisé par les organisateurs de l'événement (*cycl'eau-cross*) est une bonne trouvaille.

Dans la même veine, on pourrait proposer ***vél'eau*** ou ***vélod'eau***.

Sinon, on trouve ***[hydrocycle](https://www.carredescanotiers.fr/inventaires/lexique/hydrocycle)*** et ***[Nautilette](https://inventairebateauxduleman.ch/fr/bateau/aut00025/)*** :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

["Bateau à pédales"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateau_%C3%A0_p%C3%A9dales) est possible aussi.

*Aquabike*, comme attesté par le Gorafi (le site de fausse nouvelles rigolos, comme Onion aux États-Unis.)
[image]